# How to declare multiple [Bindable] vars on a single line... binding stops working

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

I am trying to declare multiple Bindable variables in a single line (using a single 'var' call):

```
[Bindable] public var var1:int = -1, var2:int = -1, var3:int = -1, var4:int = -1;
```

I want to use the 'var' call only once to save time (after reading this post: http://www.rozengain.com/blog/2007/05/01/some-actionscript-30-optimizations/)

The problem is I now get warnings that 'Data binding will not be able to detect assignments to "var2".'

If I declare them the traditional way (on multiple lines) I don't get the warning:

```
[Bindable] public var var1:int = -1;
[Bindable] public var var2:int = -1;
[Bindable] public var var3:int = -1;
[Bindable] public var var4:int = -1;
```

Is there a way around this?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You're trying to get minimal performance improvement from the inline declaration, while you're creating a huge overhead (comparatively anyway) by making these properties bindable.

Comment: Metadata has to be specified once per variable you want to associate with it; or at the class level.  If you specify a class as Bindable then all properties of that class will be Bindable.    Unless you're planning on creating lots of variables within a loop; I do not put much stock on performance tests that use loops to prove performance impact.

Comment: @RIAstar they're going to be bindable either way, I'm trying to make it faster. It makes perfect sense.

Comment: @ginsberg It's not going to be faster in any way. The Bindable tag will generate lots of code (getters, setters, value checking, event dispatching - the last one especially is bad for performance), whether you initially write it inline or not. And even if it wouldn't I doubt any human being would notice the difference.

Comment: @RIAstar My understanding was that event dispatching was incredibly fast; but the handler methods cause the slowdown. [I have no idea if that understanding is true, though].  I had always assumed Binding slowdown was in the Flex Framework code; not in the Flash Player's event dispatching mechanism.

Comment: @Reboog711 You may be right (except for bubbling events: they are cloned, i.e. re-instantiated, on every DisplayObject they pass). Either way there's at least one instantiation of a PropertyChangeEvent, which comes at a cost that is a hundred times higher than the intended performance gain. And what's the use of creating a bindable property if you don't intend to bind it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you put all those variables into a single class, and then make the class instance Bindable?

i.e.

```
package
{
    [Bindable]
    public class Contact
    {
        public var contactId:int;

        public var firstName:String;
        public var lastName:String;
        public var address:String;
        public var city:String;
        public var state:String;
        public var zip:String;
        public var phone:String;
        public var email:String;
    }
}
```

And then:

`[Bindable] public var myContact:Contact;`

Not only are you now saving a bit of performance by making the entire class variables Bindable, but you're following an OOP pattern.

Now you're playing with power...OOP Power!

Here's a reference:
http://coenraets.org/blog/2007/10/annotating-actionscript-classes-with-custom-metadata-simple-orm-framework-for-air/

Comment: I think this is the only way to do it, although I don't want to go through the trouble in this specific case. Thank you.